# Autosuggest termsLimit is being ignored

Tags: here-api, autosuggest

It looks like the termsLimit parameter for autosuggest is not working - unless we are doing something wrong? The following request specifies a maximum of 3 query term results but returns 5:

```
https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?in=bbox%3a-98.96484375000001,25.633671669021734,120.58593750000001,72.39307050880166&limit=20&termsLimit=3&q=oxfor&apikey=
```

Comment: We have used the same request and we did receive max query terms as 3. Could you please let us know when have you faced this issue or could you please check and provide us the response for further investigation.

Comment: The issue still seems to be happening. The query above generates 5 chainQuery results despite specifying a maximum of 3. It won't let me post the full response here as it is too long but if you run the above query you'll get 5 chainQuery results.